# I have noticed that sometimes my HD is spinning and spinning running "find command" on Xubuntu 16.04.5

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, process, find, malware

When I start my laptop the HD is spinning executing find command without reason, I tried to clean saved sessions, looking in startup programs if there is any command using find command, but I couldn't find anything strange.
What can I do to kill this process permanently ? I added a screenshot of top command and the "find" process has "user = nobody". Can be a virus running at startup or logout-login action ? Thanks Vladi
[image: Top command screenshot]

Comment: If you run `ps -fp <pid>` where <pid> is the pid of find, 458 in above list, you can see the parent-pid of the find process, which may give you an idea of who is spawning find. Eventually you will have to follow parent pids until you find the original process. If you end at the `init`process, yo are at least one process too far.